# How to elegantly return an object that is default-initialized?

Tags: c++, c++11, return, default-value, default-constructor

I have a class like below:

```
class VeryVeryVeryLongTypeName
{
    bool is_ok;

    VeryVeryVeryLongTypeName() : is_ok(false) {}
};

VeryVeryVeryLongTypeName f()
{
    VeryVeryVeryLongTypeName v;

    ... // Doing something

    if (condition_1 is true)
    {
        return v;
    }
    else
    {
        return VeryVeryVeryLongTypeName();
    }

    ... // Doing something

    if (condition_2 is true)
    {
        return v;
    }
    else
    {
        return VeryVeryVeryLongTypeName();
    }    
}
```

I think the statement `return VeryVeryVeryLongTypeName();` is very tedious and ugly, so, my question is:

**How to elegantly return an object that is default-initialized?**

or in other words:

**Is it a good idea to add a feature into the C++ standard to make the following statement is legal?**

```
return default; // instead of return VeryVeryVeryLongTypeName();
```

Comment: Why you use a very long ugly name which repulses you to use it? ;-)

Comment: A long name is not sure to seem ugly, as long as it is meaningful. I feel it ugly just because "return VeryVeryVeryLongTypeName();" is too tedious and meaningless. "return {};" is far better than the former.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is very much more succinct:

```
   return {};
```

Comment: I want to use this in some code just to give my team lead conniptions. Does this make me a bad person?

Comment: I'm curious what problems making a default constructor which doesn't have an argument with a default value explicit solves?

Comment: @Troy: Keep in mind `A(int i = 0)` is a default ctor. Answer is still valid though.

Comment: @JesseGood `explicit` is only useful for a ctor with exactly one parameter without a default value. The OP asks about a default ctor, which has no parameters without a default value.

Comment: @Troy: I think I might have misunderstood your comment. Here is another [use case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76e91d9aaf8f4760) though.

Comment: @JesseGood: Great comments. However, my solution solves [all such issues](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ead64fca04496009).

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, I +1ed it, although personally I would just type it out.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this class whose instance will implicitly convert into an instance of *desired* type automatically. This should work even if the default constructor is marked `explicit` **or if you're still using C++03**. For C++11, the accepted answer is succinct and better.

```
const struct default_t
{
     template<typename T>
     operator T() const {   return T{}; }
}default_{};
```

And use it as:

```
VeryVeryVeryLongTypeName f()
{
     //...
     return default_;
}

WithExplicitConstructor_VeryVeryVeryLongTypeName g()
{
     //...
     return default_;
}
```

[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07563814c3a87113).

You can use this solution *everywhere*, even in templates:

```
template<typename T>
typename father::template daughter<T>::grand_son_type h()
{
     //...
     return default_;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is a lot of typing and creating of a new function for each different case, when `return {};` will work for every case, as @Troy said. A decent solution for pre-C++11 though.

Comment: @cdmh: No. That wouldn't work every where. See Jesse's comments on that answer.

Comment: can you give examples?

Comment: @cdmh: See Jesse's comments on that answer.

Comment: I already replied to why Jesse's answer isn't accurate. `explicit` is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @cdmh i recommend you to open up a new question if you don't know why `explicit` is relevant to this question.

Answer (score 2):

How about `typedef` ?

```
class VeryVeryVeryLongTypeName;
typedef class VeryVeryVeryLongTypeName S;
```

And then use `S`.

See **[HERE](http://ideone.com/NSNVcc)**

Comment: What if the return type is `typename father::template daughter<T>::grand_son_type`? My solution would still work great. ;-)

Comment: @Nawaz yeah, I've mark this post as favorite just for your answer :D

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you can rely on defining a type alias. In C++11 you can use the notation

```
using SnappyName = VeryVeryVeryLongTypeName;
```

and then use `SnappyName` anywhere you want to.

Remember that you will need to come back to your code, say, six months from now. Use an approach which will help you (or your collaborators) understand unequivocally what you meant. Remember: code is written once and read many times. Code for later readability, not for present keystroke savings.

Comment: What if the return type is `typename father::template daughter<T>::grand_son_type`? My solution would still work great. ;-)

Comment: Would you use `decltype` / `declval` for a case such as that? I think it may be a good use case, but I have not yet played with them.

Answer (score 0):

You receive solution to your problem but there is something you should be aware of. The way you write the function prevent copy elusion like NVRO.

The standard authorises compilers to skip useless copy from temporary but it exists some guidelines to match the condition to enable the optimisation.

In the function body, you must either return the same named objet and nothing else, or always return an object construction. Mixing the two and you loose the very valuable optimization.